# htaccess to redirect, replacing / with?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all urls by replacing slash (/) with question mark (?):

from: domainname.nl/folder1/folder2/alias-of-article

to: domainname.nl/folder1/folder2?alias-of-article

I tried online testers like: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/
On both works the following line:

```
RewriteRule /folder2/(.*)$ /folder2?$ [L]
```

But if I added it to my htaccess it doesn't work.
Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Check [`RewriteRule` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and [`RewriteRule` Flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html):

```
RewriteRule ^/folder2/(.*)$ /folder2?$1 [R=301,L]
```

It tests if the url pattern is starting with `/folder2/` and followed by `{any characters}`, and rewrites the url to `/folder2?{any characters}`, `$1` is **RewriteRule backreferences**.

**RewriteRule Flags:**

R=301: redirect permanently

L: last rule, no further rules will be processed

Comment: Please put an explanation for your answer to help the op and others understand why/how it will solve the issue.

Comment: No this is not working. Isn't it the same as what i had?

Comment: the backreference `$1`, and did you set `AllowOverride All`?

Comment: and did you enable the `RewriteEngine`?